# Я не понимаю в чём ошибка

Tags: python

Писала код для игры. Вылезла ошибка там было написано что имя x не существует. Вот часть кода:

```py
while run:
    time.delay(50)
       
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
            x, y = e.pos

            if button_1.collidepoint(x,y):
                print('level1')
                finish = False
                level = 1
                packmen = Player('pac-3.png', 5, win_height - 80, 100, 80 , 0, 0)
                final = GameSprite('1677944907550.png',500, 360, 150, 130)
                monsters, barriers = level1()
            
            if button_2.collidepoint(x,y):
                print('level2')
                level = 2
                finish = False
                packmen = Player('pac-3.png', 5, win_height - 80, 100, 80 , 0, 0)
                final = GameSprite('1677944907550.png',50, 50, 150, 130)
                monsters, barriers = level2()

        if button_end.collidepoint(x,y):
            run = False  
        
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом примере переменная x инициализируется значением 0, но вы можете использовать любое другое значение, которое вам нужно.

```
x = 0  # или любое другое значение, которое вам нужно
y = 0

while run:
    time.delay(50)

    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
            x, y = e.pos

            if button_1.collidepoint(x,y):
                print('level1')
                finish = False
                level = 1
                packmen = Player('pac-3.png', 5, win_height - 80, 100, 80 , 0, 0)
                final = GameSprite('1677944907550.png',500, 360, 150, 130)
                monsters, barriers = level1()

            if button_2.collidepoint(x,y):
                print('level2')
                level = 2
                finish = False
                packmen = Player('pac-3.png', 5, win_height - 80, 100, 80 , 0, 0)
                final = GameSprite('1677944907550.png',50, 50, 150, 130)
                monsters, barriers = level2()

    if button_end.collidepoint(x,y):
        run = False  

    if e.type == QUIT:
        run = False
```

Comment: Ну а теперь будет `y` неопределена